# Firestore then() function not executing after set()

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a new document in the firestore using `set` function. I want to use the document data after the set function pushes data into the database.

```
            // Add each record to their respective heads
        let docRef = headCollectionRef.doc(data.headSlug).collection(recordsCollection)
            .doc(String(data.recordData.sNo))
        docRef.set(data).then(docSnap => {
            agreementData.push(
                docSnap.get().then(data => {
                    return data
                })
            )
        })
```

Nothing written in the `then()` is being executed.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`set` returns `Promise<void>`, so you don't have access to the doc data inside `then`.

This is a situation where async/await will make your code much easier to read.

```
async function cool() {
  const docRef = headCollectionRef.doc(...)

  await docRef.set(data)

  const docSnap = await docRef.get()

  agreementData.push( docSnap.data() )

}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set

Comment: This is not working. As the question says 'then' is not working, it's not about the data being there inside 'then'. So the problem is basically the set method doesn't get resolved anytime. So whatever code you will write past await won't get executed. Atleast this is not working for me.