# Firestore set() suddenly not returning in then statement and not adding docs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Have some Firestore .set() functions that are suddenly not working-- they are not doing anything in the then statement and no code after "await" is executing with them if formatted as async/await. No docs are being added to Firestore.

First had this from the Firestore docs:

```
export function addProfileToDB(advisor, uid, state) {

    firebaseDB.collection("users").doc(uid).set(profile)
        .then(function(docRef) {
            console.log("User added with ID: ", docRef.id) // never fires
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error(error) // never fires
        })

}
```

Tried a la [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008619/firestore-then-function-not-executing-after-set):

```
export async function addProfileToDB(profile, uid, state) {

  const docRef = firebaseDB.collection("users").doc(uid)

  console.log(docRef) // returns correctly

  await docRef.set(profile)

  console.log('added') // never happens

}
```

Using add() and read functions in the same setup works fine, but I need to specify the doc id (uid) in this case. Thoughts?

Comment: your code is correct, if "added" never happen it's because of set() throw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being due to a sign out user function that was being called at the same time as the addProfileToDB. Although the user being signed in wasn't required for addProfileToDB, for some reason the interruption caused the set to not go through. I moved the sign out user function to fire later and all is now working as expected. Thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the async/await version with a try catch block.
Same for the code which calls addProfileToDB (and you should await it too).
Maybe you'll see something.

If it's a cloud function that trigger addProfileToDB,  did you watch logs on the firebase console ?

Answer (score 0):

If set() throw an error, console.log('added') can't be ritched.
My solution consist to catch if there is any error.

#### Solution

```
export async function addProfileToDB(profile, uid, state) {

  const docRef = firebaseDB.collection("users").doc(uid)

  console.log(docRef) // returns correctly
  
  try {

     await docRef.set(profile)
     console.log('added')

  } catch (e) {

     console.log(e)

  }
}
```